# Why does swagger gives me ISE error when i return return JSON

Tags: asp.net-core, model-view-controller, swagger

I have the following code im not sure why swagger doesnt like it, i get this error
[image]

```
public JsonResult ProductsForTreeView(int? id)
        {
            var employees = from e in Context.ResponsibleParty
                            where (id.HasValue ? e.ProductKey == id : e.ProductKey == 0)
                            select new
                            {
                                id = e.ID,
                                Name = e.PartyName + " " + e.ProductCode,
                                hasChildren = (from q in Context.Products
                                               where (q.ID == e.ProductKey)
                                               select q
                                               ).Count() > 0
                            };

            return Json(employees.ToList());

        }
```

I get this error

> Fetch errorInternal Server Error /swagger/v1/swagger.json

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60698309/113116) discusses a similar problem, see the comments for some tips.

Comment: From your linq ,the relationship between `Products` and `ResponsibleParty`   seems to be one-to-many .I programed a demo to test , but there is no error and it returned the correct json data.[Here](https://microsoftapc-my.sharepoint.com/:u:/g/personal/v-xuelc_microsoft_com/Ec192SBSazBEi3BYcDaoldABqQGXg35u8Qb3j_uh2Mk_pg?e=XM7F6o) is my demo.You could refer to and check the difference between yours.  If you want the community review and debug the code , could you share more detail about the startup.cs and model design or a complete demo that can reproduce the issue?